# What is this thing that holds widespread bathroom faucet handle to sink? How do I tighten it?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, tools

I have a Pfister widespread bathroom faucet.

As I was working on a leak and replacing the cartridge in one of the handles, I managed to loosen the other handle completely to where this part fell off:

[image: Image of part that fell off]

It seems that it attaches to the bottom of the handle where the little metal pieces protrude as shown here from the top:

[image: Image of part of faucet where thing that fell off should attach]

When I google, I find a lot of talk about using a basin wrench to tighten plastic nuts, but it seems like this contraption is something else entirely.

Can anyone enlighten me on (i) the names of the pieces and (ii) how I can re-attach the metal part from below the sink and then tighten it somehow?

Thanks!!!

UPDATE: Based on @JPhi1618's assistance below, you have to remove the handle (there is a cap which you can remove with your fingers or a flat-topped screwdriver, then a Phillips screw that you have to unscrew, THEN the plastic piece unscrews but for me this required quite a bunch of WD-40). Then, I made it to this:

[image]

Ended up buying two of these https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-10-in-Heavy-Duty-Straight-Pipe-Wrench-31010/100075882 RIDGID
10 in. Heavy-Duty Straight Pipe Wrenches. One is placed on flat portion of washer (?) shown by red arrow, other is placed on flat portion shown with yellow arrow.

Now, turn the wrench attached to the yellow arrow COUNTERCLOCKWISE while turning the washer shown with the red arrow CLOCKWISE. After some elbow grease, the washer started to turn, and I was then able to continue turning with my hand only. This lowered the carrier and I was able to re-attached the "gravity toggle" that fell off, then lower it under the sink, and turn the washer shown with the red arrow by hand COUNTERCLOCKWISE until it was tight.

Hope that helps someone! Still waiting for Pfister to tell me exact model of the faucet (I submitted a few tickets to them, haven't called yet).

Comment: If the other handle is still intact, look under the sink and locate the part in question. I am pretty sure where it goes but to explain it would take a lot longer to type out than what it would take to look at the other one that should still be in place. A short explanation is, it goes around the threaded tube that goes through the hole in the sink, the 2 "legs" pointing up. The the side is open so it will slip right in place. The nut should still be there, just needs to be tighter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a faucet that is designed to install from the top only.  Price Pfister calls it [Top Pfit](https://www.pfisterfaucets.com/kitchen/innovations/top-pfit).  The piece you have pictured was probably over tightened, bent, and popped off.

**Update:** It looks like the old name for this was "Twist Pfit" back when they used it for bathroom pfaucets.  Top Pfit seems to be a new name they use for kitchen pfaucets.

It works like a toggle bolt.  It lines up with the pipe to slip into the sink hole then it flops down to a horizontal position where you use a nut or screw on the top side to tighten it.

If you remove the handle from that side valve, you should be able to figure out what to turn to make the carrier with the studs on the side move up and down.  Once you figure it out, the toggle will need to be bent back into shape and snapped back in place.  DO NOT over tighten the valve once you figure it all out.  You can use plumbers putty or even silicone if you are desperate to hold it in place semi-permanently, but over tightening will only get you back to where you are now.

If you look through the PF site, you might find some installation instructions close to your faucet if you need any help, but the design may have changed slightly over the years.

Pictures from found install manual:

[image: Instructions]  [image: Instructions]

Comment: Pretty cool system, although it looks like the pivot lugs that allowed the part to fail could be a bit longer. The OP just needs to squeeze it back over the lugs/pins and do what it takes to reset it. Unless the faucet spout is a one time setting.....

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand correctly, next steps would be: 1. Remove handle, 2. Figure out how to lower carrier with studs, 3. Re-snap the toggle back into place FROM THE TOP OF THE SINK (?), 4. Let the toggle drop down and then snap into place, and 5. Raise the carrier with the studs until tight but not too tight? Thanks!!!

Comment: @stackexchangediy, Sounds good.  Maybe 2.5 - straighten out the toggle piece if it seems bent in person.  That pic makes the narrow "arms" seem bent out, but maybe it's just the photo.  You can probably tell by handling it if it got bent or not.

Comment: Thanks, so I think the carrier with the studs itself is stuck. It looks like it should just turn around the part below the faucet handle but it doesn't really turn. Besides WD-40, any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The carrier will not turn.  It moves up and down. There will be screw or nut under the handle that turns and moves the carrier.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Hmm... in that case, I'm quite stumped how to move it up and down. I took a bunch of photos with the handle off (see below) - any suggestions what I should turn? [top 1](https://i.imgur.com/Ztdvcjo.jpg) [top 2](https://i.imgur.com/FRMhe8b.jpg) [side 1](https://i.imgur.com/f540esG.jpg) [side 2](https://i.imgur.com/nzKh0iT.jpg) [under sink](https://i.imgur.com/zoXkuKi.jpg) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... in that case, I'm quite stumped how to move it up and down. I took a bunch of photos with the handle off (see below) - any suggestions what I should turn? [1](https://i.imgur.com/Ztdvcjo.jpg) [2](https://i.imgur.com/FRMhe8b.jpg) [3](https://i.imgur.com/f540esG.jpg) [4](https://i.imgur.com/nzKh0iT.jpg) [5](https://i.imgur.com/zoXkuKi.jpg) . Thanks! @JPhi1618

Comment: There are flat spots on the larger threads above the sink, and there is an obvious smaller hex shape to put a wrench on.  Do they turn relative to each other? I searched for more instruction manuals on price pfister manuals and didn't see one exactly like it.  I've seen one of these top-down install faucets, just not this exact model.

Comment: Thanks! I think I found a manual for a similar product: https://s7d1.scene7.com/is/content/Pfister/29421-0100  . The hex shape to put a wrench on is part of the cartridge similar to the one I changed on the other side ( see https://www.homedepot.com/p/Pfister-S10-900-1-13-16-in-L-Hot-Cold-Replacement-Ceramic-Disc-Cartridge-130453/205383586 for a nice picture ) . Per the manual I linked above, page 4, I think what should be turning is the flat spots on the larger threads above the sink and the gunky brown medal disk that I am holding in several of the photos. I will try to move them when home.

Comment: @stackexchangediy, aww, I was hoping for a link.

Comment: Edited my original post. Sorry I prematurely posted it.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thanks, I finally got it fixed based on your help. I added and update to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a gravity toggle.

If so it's holes should fit over the lugs of the nut part having its arched part facing down.